# truncate all category related table in magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2

We have been experimenting with syncing our existing database(not Magento) to Magento 2.3.4.In the process, we have created over 1000 categories, but then we rearranged all the IDs to sync with our system.now i want to truncate all category.is it possible

Comment: hi anyone knows

Answer (score 0):

Why don't look for this link:https://gist.github.com/rafaelstz/9b8f14c6ec396e5d52bcd9024cd26c29

Let me know if it helps you!